# Как правильно подключить bootstrap.css и свои стили написанные на sass?

Tags: css, bootstrap, sass, scss

Подключаю к сайту стандартный bootstrap.css и свой (через Koala скомпиленный из .scss) файл стилей style.css 
Bootstrap.css перебивает стили style.css. А должно быть наоборот.
Кто знает как правильно подключить бутсрап, что бы он не перебивал стили написанные и скомпиленные на scss ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стиль применяется вот тут:
  Navbar example [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление**

[image: Скрин с devTools стилей с этого элемента на странице]

[image: этот же скрин, только в другом разрешении экрана (приоритет стилей снова меняется)]

этот же скрин, только в другом разрешении экрана (приоритет стилей снова меняется)

Comment: пример стилей, которые перебивает бутстрап можете привести?

Comment: смотрите ниже, там скриншоты

Comment: Скрин с devTools стилей с этого элемента на странице скинь

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев скинул ниже

Comment: Вставьте код тексом, а не изобращением.

Comment: Ты используешь bootstrap 2? Просто в нем есть косяк, там почти все элементы используют !important в своих стилях. Если используешь второй, придется подключать 3й, либо в своих стилях писать `!important`. PS. Извини за ожидание)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев я пользуюсь только bootstrap 3 .

Answer (score 1):

Наследование немного не так работает. В твоем случае нужно не просто создавать класс `.artic`, а говорить что он лежит в `.jumbotron`

Т.е обязательно писать так:
`.jumbotron .artic`

А не: `.arctic`

Пример: http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/aNWazR

Comment: Действительно, надо было обратить внимание на _.jumbotron_ Спасибо!